# How to get back hyperparameters from a trained world2vec model gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, hyperparameters

I have a trained word2vec model which I need to train further with more data. I want to use the same hyperparameters that is used while training the model for the new model as well. But I don't want to hardcode it. Is there a method which I can use to get the hyperparameters used while training the existing model.
I am using Gensim word2vec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any full `Word2Vec` model has every metaparameter that was supplied at its initial creation somewhere in its object properties.

It's almost always on the model itself, using the exact same name as was used for the constructor parameters. So, `model.window` will return the `window`, etc - and thus you can just create a new model pulling each value from the old model.

Note that continuing training on an already-trained model involves a lot of thorny tradeoffs.

For example, the `.build_vocab(..., update=True)` on an existing model won't be applying `min_count` consistently against all word totals from all prior calls, but only those in the latest 'batch'.

The proper learning-rate (`alpha` to `min_alpha` values) for incremental updates isn't well-defined by theory or rules-of-thumb. And if the vocabulary & word-balance in the new texts mainly train some words, not all, those recently-updated words can be pulled arbitrarily out of strong-comparability-alignment with earlier words that didn't get more training. (The underlying method of mdoel optimization, stochastic gradient descent, is best-grounded when all training texts are given equal training attention, without any subset begin intensely trained later.)

Answer (score 1):

### Use `save` and `load` methods

After model is trained, save the model to disk. For retraining, load the saved model, update the vocabulary if your new training data has any unseen words and start training again. Check the official docs [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#usage-examples).

**Working example (commented inline)**

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import numpy as np

# Stage 1
sentences = ["an apple on the tree".split(), "a cat on the table".split()]

model = Word2Vec(min_count=1)
model.build_vocab(sentences)  # prepare the model vocabulary
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=2) # Train 
model.save("word2vec.model") # Save the model
s1 = np.sum(model.wv.vectors[0]) # Get the vector sum of 'a' for testing
print (model.wv.vocab)
print ("\n")

# Stage 2
sentences = ["sky is high".split(), "ocean is blue".split()] 

model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model") # Load the last saved model
model.build_vocab(sentences, update=True)  # prepare the model vocabulary
model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=2) # Train
# since 'a' is not in new train data its vector(word2vec)) should remain same
assert s1 == np.sum(model.wv.vectors[0]) 
print (model.wv.vocab)
```

Output:

```
{'a': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378f84e10>,
 'an': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378fb7810>,
 'apple': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378fb7e90>,
 'cat': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378f84b10>,
 'on': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd3764695d0>,
 'table': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378f84950>,
 'the': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd376469490>,
 'tree': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd376469b50>}

{'a': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd3797f3850>,
 'an': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd376469fd0>,
 'apple': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd375b8efd0>,
 'blue': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649a9d0>,
 'cat': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649a450>,
 'high': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649afd0>,
 'is': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649aa90>,
 'ocean': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649a7d0>,
 'on': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd375b8ef50>,
 'sky': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378f79ed0>,
 'table': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd37649a850>,
 'the': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd375b8eed0>,
 'tree': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fd378e3c190>}
```

Comment: Is `model.build_vocab()` necessary or is it being done automatically as it trains? I haven't called this method while building the initial model also

Comment: you must first build vocabulary before training the model. Second build is require to update the vocabulary with new words.